# Setting categories using VBA on a selection does not seem to work in Outlook 2007

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to set the mail message categories for the current selection. When I run the macro I end up in only a single message being set to the given categorie. I Use the following code (and have also tried to use a do until..loop using the `selection.count`):

```
Sub SetSelectionComplete()
    Dim mailMsg As MailItem

    For Each mailMsg In Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
        mailMsg.Categories = "Complete"
    Next

End Sub
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How many items are actually selected? Put a `Msgbox(ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count)` before the loop

Comment: 3 items, sometimes the first gets the category sometimes the second one but never all of them...

Comment: Have you tried for i=selection.count to 1 step -1? Sometimes it is necessary to go backwards through collections because the change to the data changes the collection.

Comment: yes I tried with the same result.

count = selection.count
do until count=0
   :
  count = count-1
loop

Comment: I need to add that I also move the message to a different folder and found out that setting the category before or after the move gives different results. If I tag before the move things seem working although not 100%. Next thing I'm going to try is to disable the standard rule "Clear categoryies on (incoming) mail"

Answer (score 5):

Save the **mailMsg** item each time, like this:

```
Sub SetSelectionComplete()
    Dim mailMsg As MailItem
    For Each mailMsg In Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
        mailMsg.Categories = "Complete"
        mailMsg.Save
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Janco
You need to call Mailitem.Save
As Remou says working with selection its a good to work backwards. 
Marcus