# Set Email Category

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to add a category to each email as the loop goes down:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SaveAttachmentsFromSelectedItemsPDF2_ForNext()

    Dim currentItem As Object
    Dim currentAttachment As Attachment
    Dim saveToFolder As String
    Dim savedFileCountPDF As Long
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long

    saveToFolder = "c:\dev\outlookexport" 'change the path accordingly

    savedFileCountPDF = 0
    
    For i = 1 To ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count
        
        Set currentItem = ActiveExplorer.Selection(i)
    
        For j = 1 To currentItem.Attachments.Count
                    
            Set currentAttachment = currentItem.Attachments(j)
            
            If UCase(Right(currentAttachment.DisplayName, 5)) = UCase(".xlsx") Then
                currentAttachment.SaveAsFile saveToFolder & "\" & _
                Left(currentAttachment.DisplayName, Len(currentAttachment.DisplayName) - 5) & ".xlsx"
                savedFileCountPDF = savedFileCountPDF + 1
            End If
            
            ' If For Next does not release memory automatically then
            '  uncomment to see if this has an impact
            'Set currentAttachment = Nothing
            
        Next
        
        ' If For Next does not release memory automatically then
        '  uncomment to see if this has an impact
        'Set currentItem = Nothing
        
    Next
    
    MsgBox "Number of PDF files saved: " & savedFileCountPDF, vbInformation

End Sub
```

The code to set categories seems to be:

```
.Categories = "MyCategory"
```

When I add this to my code (under `For i = 1...`) it gives me an error:

> "Unqualified reference"

How do I add a category to the emails as the loop goes down the list of selected emails?

Comment: **"it gives me an error"** is not helpful. Would you please share the error code with us?

Comment: Sorry it says invalid or unqualified reference

Comment: The line *.Categories = "MyCategory"* should be **currentItem.Categories = "MyCategory"**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting categories using VBA on a selection does not seem to work in Outlook 2007](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377662/setting-categories-using-vba-on-a-selection-does-not-seem-to-work-in-outlook-200)

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the object in the code:

```
For i = 1 To ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count

    Set currentItem = ActiveExplorer.Selection(i)

    currentItem.Categories = "MyCategory"
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to show your "with" statement.
Secondly, you need to save the message afterwards `(currentItem.Save`).